# Не изменяется класс элемента с помощью js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка:

```js
var div = document.querySelector("#login");
        div.className = "false";
        div.innerHTML = "Слишком маленький логин";
        alogin = false;
```

```css
#login .false{
  position: relative;
  left: 90px;
  bottom: 80px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#login .true{
  position: relative;
  left: 90px;
  bottom: 80px;
  color: green;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="login"></div>
```

Что выходит (текст должен быть красным и под надписью `"Регистрация"`, Т.К .класс `"false"`):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS селекторы неправильные. Должно быть

```
#login.false{
  position: relative;
  left: 90px;
  bottom: 80px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#login.true{
  position: relative;
  left: 90px;
  bottom: 80px;
  color: green;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```